# Inner join and null value

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have 3 tables

1. table1
2. table2
3. table3

i am applying inner join on to retrieve the data from all these tables, 
but i am not getting any row as soon as any value inside any of the table is null can somebody tell me the correct way of doing this.

```
select name, subject, class
from table1 
inner join table2
on table1.subjectId = table2.subjectId
inner join table3
on table1.classId = table3.classId
where studentId = 3
```

on studentId 3 there is no subject in table2 and hence it is not giving any result for all of the tables.

Comment: This is how it's meant to work. Maybe you want an outer join of some kind.

Comment: Here is a [good Venn Diagram](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) that helps illustrate what the different types of joins do. You all of Table A but you also want Table B where it is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a left join.

```
select name, subject, class 
from table1
    left join table2 on table1.subjectId = table2.subjectId
    left join table3 on table1.classId = table3.classId
where studentId = 3
```